# How to append value of a JSON response in a list (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

i am getting response from request.post() as this:

```
{'total': 3,
 'files': [{'fileName': 'abc.mp4', 'size': '123'},
           {'fileName': 'def.mp4', 'size': '456'},
           {'fileName': 'ghi.mp4', 'size': '789'}]
}
```

i just want the filename value from this response and store it in an str list.

i have tried the following loop to do the same but it is showing some error:

```
        fileNames = []
        for files in response.json()["files"]:
            fileNames.append(files["filename"])
```

i expected the list of filenames but got some error

Comment: What error did you get? "Some error" is not helpful.

Comment: What error did you get? Post full traceback.

Comment: You are getting a KeyError because you forgot that dictionary keys (when they are strings) are case-sensitive

Comment: Yes, correct I was getting the KeyError, Thank you so much @Pingu I changed the name and it did the work..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do via list comprehension as well:

```
fileNames = [files["fileName"] for files in response.json()["files"]]
```

and as stated by others as well it should be `"fileName"` instead of `"filename"`

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```py
fileNames = []
for files in response.json()["files"]:
    fileNames.append(files["fileName"])
```

I think you wrote `"filename"` instead of `"fileName"` ("Name" capitalised).

Answer (score 2):

the key is of a Dict is case sensitive, so you need to change the used key inside the loop with an upper case "N":

```
    fileNames = []
    for files in response.json()["files"]:
        fileNames.append(files["fileName"])
```

I tested this, and you will get just the file names in the "fileNames" list.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the KeyError, I just changed the key value to fileName instead of filename and it solved the problem.